# ode45/fsolve issue for Shooting Method solution to BVP

Tags: matlab, optimization, differential-equations, ode

I'm trying to solve a boundary value problem in MATLAB using the shooting method. However, when I try to pass my function through fsolve, I'm getting warnings like:
Warning: Failure at t=-9.462647e+001.  Unable to meet integration tolerances without reducing the step size below the smallest value
allowed (2.273737e-013) at time t.

I've tried some of the common workarounds like using different ODE solvers and changing the tolerances in the ODE solve and fsolve but to no avail. Currently, when I run fsolve on my parameters, it changes nothing and it's the same as my initial guess.

I've included the code for the main script file as well as the function file called by fsolve.

```
%% Main file
% PARAMETERS
% propanol (fig2, curve3, p337) 
E=6.5; %2.5
K=0.0474;

% GUESSES
infinity=100; % numerical approximation of infinity
x=0; % expanded around x=0
x0=3;
B0=-2*10^(-8);
B1=0.01;
% Guess for P
P=-1+3*B0*(1-(E/(K+1)))*exp((x-x0)*sqrt(3*E/(K+1)));
% Guess for P'
PI=sqrt(3*E/(K+1))*3*B0*(1-(E/(K+1)))*exp((x-x0)*sqrt(3*E/(K+1)));
% Guess for H
H=1+B0*exp((x-x0)*sqrt(3*E/(K+1)))+B1*exp((x-x0)*sqrt(3));
% Guess for H' (contact angle in degrees)
HI=sqrt(3*E/(K+1))*B0*exp((x-x0)*sqrt(3*E/(K+1)))+sqrt(3)*B1*exp((x-x0)*sqrt(3));

% FUNCTION
f=@(t,x) [x(2); ...
    3*E*(1+x(1))/((1+K*x(3))*(x(3))^3) - 3*x(2) * x(4)/(x(3));...
    x(4);...
    -1/(x(3)^3) - x(1)];

% SHOOTING METHOD
tspan=[-infinity, infinity];
myguess=[P, PI, H, HI]; % initial guess for P', H'
[actualvalue, Fval, exitflag]=fsolve('shootingfunc_thin_100',myguess);
init=actualvalue; % new initial paramaters
[t,X]=ode45(f,tspan,init);

%% Function file
function [ f ] = shootingfunc_thin_100( a )
%shootingfunc_thin: Shooting from thin to thick
%   optimizes P=0 at infinity only
E=6.5;
K=0.0474;

fun=@(t,x) [x(2); ...
    3*E*(1+x(1))/((1+K*x(3))*(x(3))^3) - 3*x(2) * x(4)/(x(3));...
    x(4);...
    -1/(x(3)^3) - x(1)];

infinity=10^2;
tspan=[-infinity, infinity];
init=[-1 a(2) 1 a(4)]; % initial conditions at thin
%options=odeset('RelTol',1e-10); %'RelTol',1e-16
[t,x]=ode45(fun,tspan,init);
f=x(end,1);
end
```

Comment: Does it actually give an error or only warnings?
You may want to run it with `dbstop if error` or `dbstop if warning`

Comment: Sorry for being imprecise. It gives warnings and continues to run, but ultimately does nothing. The value returned by fsolve is the same as the value put in. The warning is `> In ode45 at 367`

Comment: Could you state the ODE you are integrating and the BVP behind it?  Inferring this directly from code is a heavy task for someone before even considering whats wrong.  I'm curious why the time span on ode45 is -inf to inf though... it should never finish or start?